# How to make the script in this "function isian" using a trigger onChange. it uses a trigger onFormSubmit how to change it can use an onchange trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to create a script in this “function isian” using the onChange trigger. This script uses the onFormSubmit trigger, how to change it so that it can use the onchange trigger. I have data in a spreadsheet that uses a trigger on form submit in this script which is triggered from a google form, I want to change the trigger using the onChange trigger how do I do it or what does the script and where I place it, I'm still very new to this. Hope someone can help me?

```js
var token = 'Masukan token yang didapat dari BotFather';
var telegramUrl = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token;
var webAppUrl = 'masukan url server yang didapat dari publish web app'


//ini untuk mengaktifkan Server Bot nya
function setWebhook(){
  var url = telegramUrl+'/setWebhook?url='+webAppUrl;
  var response =   UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  
  Logger.log(response.getContentText())
}


function doPost(e){
  
  //masukan id google sheet tempat dimana menyimpan data toko
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   
  //menangkap request dari server telegram
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  
  //variabel text digunakan untuk menyimpan text yang dikirim oleh user
  var text = contents.message.text;
  //variabel yang digunakan untuk menyimpan id percakapan dari user
  var id = contents.message.chat.id;
  
  //memberi respon jika text yang dikirim user adalah kata reg
  if(text == "reg"){
    
    var balasPesan = "terima kasih anda sudah terdaftar di layanan bot ini"
    //memasukan chat id panitia ke sheet chat_id pada baris 2 kolom 1   
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("chat_id").getRange(2,1).setValue(id)
    kirimPesan(id,balasPesan)
  
  }else{
    
   var pesan= "*Selamat datang di Menu PPDB* \n"
    +"Bot ini terdiri dari beberapa menu   : \n"
    +"a. Register layanan \n"
    +"Ketik : reg \n";
    kirimPesan(id,pesan,'markdown');
  }  
}


//fungsi ini digunakan untuk mengirim pesan
function kirimPesan(chatid, pesan, parseMode, replyMarkup) {
  var formData = {
     'chat_id': chatid,
     'text': pesan
  };
  
  if ( (typeof parseMode !== 'undefined') || (typeof parseMode !== null) )  {
    formData['parse_mode'] = parseMode;
  }
  
  if ( (typeof replyMarkup !== 'undefined') || (typeof replyMarkup !== null) )  {
    formData['reply_markup'] = replyMarkup;
  }
  
  var ret = request('sendMessage', formData);
  return ret;
}
  
function request(method,data){
  
  var options = {
    'method':'post',
    'contentType':'application/json',
    'payload':JSON.stringify(data)
  };
 

  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(telegramUrl+'/'+method,options)
  
}

function isian(e){
  var waktuDaftar = e.values[0]
  var nama = e.values[1]
  var smp = e.values[2]
  var jurusan = e.values[3]
  var noHp = e.values[4]
  
  
  var template = DriveApp.getFileById("Masukan id template document pendaftaran")
  var folderSimpanFile = DriveApp.getFolderById("Masukan id Folder yang digunakan untuk menyimpan file")
  //membuat copyan dari template dengan nama dari field yang di isikan pendaftar
  var copyTemplate = template.makeCopy(jurusan+" "+nama+" "+smp, folderSimpanFile)
  //membuka dokumen tersebut    
  var docPendaftar = DocumentApp.openById(copyTemplate.getId())
  //mendapatkan tag template untuk diganti dengan isian dari google form    
  var bodyDoc = docPendaftar.getBody()
  
  bodyDoc.replaceText("{{Nama}}", nama)
  bodyDoc.replaceText("{{SMP}}", smp)
  bodyDoc.replaceText("{{Jurusan}}", jurusan)
  //menyimpan dan menutup inputan dari pendaftar 
  docPendaftar.saveAndClose()
  //membuka dokumen dan merubahnya menjadi pdf
  var pdf = DocumentApp.openById(copyTemplate.getId()).getAs('application/pdf')
  //membuat link pdf nya
  var urlPdf = folderSimpanFile.createFile(pdf).getDownloadUrl()
  //mendapatkan chat id dari bot panitia ppdb
  var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("chat_id").getRange(2,1).getValue()
  
  //Mengirim pesan ke panitia ppdb ketika ada pendaftar
  var pesan= "Mohon untuk segera dikonfirmasi pendaftar  \n"
    +"Nama    : "+ nama+" \n"
    +"SMP     : "+ smp+"\n"
    +"Pilihan : "+ jurusan+"\n"
    +"WA      : wa.me/62"+noHp+"?text=*Assalamualikum%2CKami%20dari%20Panitia%20PPDB%20SMK%20Pemalang*%0ABerikut%20ini%20adalah%20bukti%20pendaftaran%20Anda%20%3A\n"
    +"Bukti   : "+ urlPdf+"\n"      
    kirimPesan(id,pesan);
}
```

Comment: If you wish to use the event object of the onFormSubmit then you must use that trigger.  The onChange trigger has no knowledge of the form submission and there no knowledge of the submision data.  I don't if onChange trigger will fire on a form submission.

Comment: I want this script to be changed so that it can use triggers onChange, but I don't know what to change and how to change this code so that it can use triggers onChange, because currently this code uses triggers onFormSubmit. how to change it so that it can be used when the row is filled manually and not from form submission

Comment: The only way to possibly do that would result in code that is prone to many errors and may produce unreliable results.  I would not recommend it.